# How to omit "Aws :: ECSCredentials.new" in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

Currently, the way to write the source differs depending on the execution environment
and I want to fix it to a unified writing style.

The code is as follows depending on the environment.

When connecting to s3 with ECS:

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: Settings.aws.region, credentials: Aws::ECSCredentials.new)
```

When connecting to s3 with not ECS:

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: Settings.aws.region)
```

When connecting to AWS s3 on ECS, an error occurs if there are no credentials.

Let me know If there is a way to improve.

Comment: Hi @negabaro were you able to solve this? I am having issue.